# Always center items in a gridview (horizontally)

Tags: android, gridview, user-interface, center

I want to have a GridView that fill the whole space horizontally, but are limited vertically.
I then want to add items to this GridView that always are centered horizontally. Items will be added dynamically, but I always want these to be centered horizontally in the GridView.

This is my GridView definition in my layout xml:

```
 <GridView
   android:id="@+id/my_grid_view"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:background="@color/soft"
   android:columnWidth="15dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:verticalSpacing="0px" />
```

The gravity tag doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score -1):

Gridview properties Layout height wrap contents layout width match parent. Item properties gravity center

Comment: This didn't work. As the items are added dynamically I used the method setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) on the View returned by BaseAdapter.getView(...);

Comment: Maybe @miviaa could post the answer he/she given aboth and mark it!

Comment: @D4ddy-LiLd4rk  Are you sure this works?  It didn't center the items for me.